# how to test this portion of code

Tags: java, junit

Hello I'm writting junit test how can I test this method .. this is only part of this method :

```
public MyClass{

public void myMethod(){
List<myObject> list = readData();
}
}
```

How will I make the test for this? ReadData is a private method inside MyClass?

Comment: I think you need to extend your example a bit. As it stands, the method has no visible behavior at all (except for returning), so there's nothing to test.

Comment: Does 'readData' modify a MyClass instance's state? If so, you should test for the changed state. If not, I don't understand what 'readData' does.

Comment: List<myObject> is wrong. You should specify a class between the angle brackets, for example List<MyClass>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written, it doesn't make sense to test `myMethod()` unless `readData()` changes the instance state the way Frank Grimm mentioned. One thing to do would be to change `myMethod()` so that it puts `list` into a `List` instance variable. Then you might do something like this:

```
@Test
public void testThatReadDataReturnsACorrectList(){
   MyClass inst = new MyClass(); // Add args to ctor call if needed - maybe a file path that readData() will use?
   inst.myMethod();

   // Create a list of MyClasses that match what you expect readData() to return:
   List<MyClass> expectedList = new List<>();
   expectedList.Add(new MyClass(/* Some arguments */));
   expectedList.Add(new MyClass(/* Some more arguments */));
   expectedList.Add(new MyClass(/* Some other arguments */));

   // Assert that the list you created matches the list you get back from 
   assertArrayEquals("Did not get the list expected", expectedList.ToArray(), inst.getList().ToArray());

}
```

You'd still have to write `MyClass.getList()` to return the `List` instance variable.

To be robust, you could make the `MyClass` constructor accept an object that implements an interface like `IMyReadInterface`. `readData()` would use that object. Then in your test, you could instantiate a mock that also implements `IMyReadInterface`, configure the mock to provide the data needed so that `readData()` works correctly, and construct `inst` with that mock.

Answer (score 1):

You can always test the List object to see if it contains all of the elements that readData() is supposed to insert into the list.  Make a public method that returns the list and you can compare the length and elements in that list to what you are expecting to be in there.

Answer (score 0):

Unless we know more about the method, all you really need to test is that the return from readData is in a format that fits into your generic list. Otherwise, its hard to recommend anything without knowing more about whats going on in your private method.